# How do i send the number of users in all guilds combined?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im using `message.client.guilds.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size` to output the number of users in all guilds combined but im getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined` but cache works in this code to cache all guilds `message.client.guilds.cache.size`. So how can i fix this and output number of users in all guilds combined?

Comment: can you console.log(message.client.guilds) and post it here?

Comment: @RanMarciano i got `9`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all, [`message.client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) returns a [`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager), which does not have a `members` property.

To get all the members in every guild, you need a way to iterate through every guild, such as the [`Collection.prototype.each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) method.

```js
message.client.guilds.each((guild) =>
 // this function will be executed for every element (guild) in the collection
 console.log(`${guild.name} has ${guild.members.cache.size} members`)
);
```

If you'd like to add all of the counts together, you should use [`Collection.prototype.reduce()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=reduce)

```js
message.client.guilds.reduce((acc, guild) => acc + guild.members.cache.size, 0);
```

The difference between the above snippet and the second snippet you provided in your code:

```js
// this line is looking at the GuildMemberManager cache (`guild.members.cache`)
message.client.guilds.reduce((acc, guild) => acc + guild.members.cache.size, 0);
// this line is looking at the GuildManager cache (`client.guilds.cache`)
message.client.guilds.cache.size;
```

You need to look at *both* caches. The aforementioned [`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager) is not a collection of guilds, so any attempt to loop through them will not work.

```js
message.client.guilds.cache.reduce(
 (acc, guild) => acc + guild.members.cache.size,
 0
);
```

Also, this count would only be looking at the cached members from each guild, which is very rarely all of them. The best solution would be looking at the member count directly from the guild object, which is not subject to caching behavior.

```js
message.client.guilds.cache.reduce((acc, guild) => acc + guild.memberCount, 0);
```